# One word for doing something in a certian way while missing the essential point of doing it in such a way

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, people in South Korea love measuring your knowledge through a standardised test.

There are thousands of study aid books and private tutors to help students get high scores in tests.

Some study aid books advertise that you will only have to study what is on the test to minimise the effort that you have to put in.

If it were an English test, the purpose of the test should be to make sure that whoever gets a high score is fluent in English.

So rather than helping you become more knowledgeable, it analyses the questions that have been on the test so far, and then it shows you what the answers to the questions are.

Another example could be those people who use the leaked exam and answers to pass some certificate exams.

I was thinking if there was a word like

> you-missed-the-whole-point-ism

.

Comment: The purpose of the test is *misconstrued*, but it is an entrance exam, after all, and passing them is big business in other countries too.

Comment: A “[teach-to-the-test mentality](http://newsprintnow.net/opinion/2014/10/15/opinion-teach-to-the-test-mentality-plagues-u-s-education-system/)” (or simply a “[test mentality](https://books.google.com/books?id=jTHXWLzlqwIC&pg=PA49&dq=%22test+mentality%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=d25sVfuAJK7IsQT564GICA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBDge#v=onepage&q=%22test%20mentality%22&f=false)”) describes well what you’re talking about, but in two words, not one.  “Teaching-to-the-test” as a hyphenated (and coined?) verb might work.

Comment: The standard idiom for this is "***missing the forest for the trees***", but I'm not aware of any single word which captures the same sentiment.

Comment: Well, it is *missing the point*.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [Hitting the target but missing the point](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/165406/8019)

Comment: I have from time to time claimed to "cargo-cult" my way through a problem, by solving it at a surface level at least, based on incompletely understood prior cases. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word, but...

"[defeat the purpose](http://www.yourdictionary.com/defeat-the-purpose)" could work here

> to be against the purpose of something, to nullify the purpose of something

Answer (score 0):

As extended beyond its medical meaning of “nearsightedness”, “myopic” and “myopia” mean “shortsightedness”:

> [Myopic](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/myopic) students (and
>   myopic educators) have no interest in anything beyond what's on the
>   test.

Answer (score 0):

A word that could fit this is **legalistic**, though it has some religious connotations. It is often accompanied with the idea of "following the letter of the law and forsaking the spirit of the law".

I was trying to find a single word that would fit someone who looks for loopholes to get something without going through standard procedure, but I'm pulling a blank.